# Duplicate messages in kafka when using debezium

Tags: cdc, debezium, mysqlbinlog

I read internals of debezium, but it also can send duplicate messages to kafka, if there is some failure at connector just before updating offset in bin log. In that case, consumer needs to be idempotent. Is there any way we can avoid duplicate message in kafka ??

Comment: No there is none, but you can remove duplicates using KSQL or streams or in consumer logic.

Comment: Sometimes if consumer is some 3rd party, it becomes little overhead for them to do maintain idempotency. I was looking for a solution where everything could be controlled at producer side itself. Can you please explain KSQL more..

Comment: Correct, in your case, neither source or sink connectors are custom so you need to rely on their behavior but, what can be done is add a step in between to filter/de-dup your data and then push it to a new stream. And finally, use this stream for your sink connector. 
[Here](https://www.confluent.io/stream-processing-cookbook/ksql-recipes/data-filtering/) is an example of data filtering using KSQL 
You can find all the details about ksql and stream [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams-ksql.html).